# How do I make my socket keep trying to connect even after the connection is closed?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

So I am writing this program that will allow me to run commands from a different computer on the same network (my own version of ssh) in Python. I want the client program to run in the background of the target which I've already figured out the logistics to. What I would like to do is start the client program and never have to start it again but after I close the server program on the host computer, I get tons of errors. What I would like to do is after I close the host program, the client will continue to try to connect to the server program until I run it again. The code for my client program is here:

```
import socket
import os

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


def connect():
    try:
        s.connect(('localhost', 1234))
    except:
        connect()


while True:
    connect()
    while True:
        try:
            msg = s.recv(1024)
            os.system(msg.decode("utf-8"))
        except:
            s.connect('localhost', 1234)
```

The code for my host program is here:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('localhost', 1234))
s.listen(5)


def main():
    while True:
        clientsocket, address = s.accept()
        while address != None:
            message = input("Enter Message: ")
            messageb = message.encode("utf-8")
            clientsocket.send(messageb)

main()
```

Note: I will change the address from localhost when I put this on a different computer.

Comment: Tons of errors such as what? NB Do't use recursion for iteration.

Comment: By tons of errors I mean it says that there is an error trying to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never do the following to start over a function without understanding the consequences of recursion.  A function calling itself is called recursion and uses stack space.  This will crash if the stack hits the recursion limit.

```
def connect():
    try:
        s.connect(('localhost', 1234))
    except:
        connect()
```

Here's a solution.

**client.py:**

```
import socket
import time

while True:
    s = socket.socket()
    try:
        print('Trying to connect...')
        s.connect(('localhost',8000))
        print('Connected.')
        try:
            while True:
                data = s.recv(1024)
                if not data: break   # server closed connection if nothing received.
                print(data)
        finally:
            s.close()
            print('Disconnected.')
    except ConnectionError:  # Any type of connection error, e.g. refused, aborted, reset.
        time.sleep(1)
```

**server.py:**

```
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('',8000))
s.listen()
while True:
    c,a = s.accept()
    print(f'Connected: {a}')
    try:
        while True:
            c.send(b'message')
            time.sleep(1)
    except ConnectionError:
        c.close()
        print(f'Disconnected: {a}')
```

Note also that TCP is a streaming protocol.  It has no concept of messages.  Take the `time.sleep(1)` out and the messages will all run together.  A proper implementation will have a protocol to extract complete messages from the byte stream such as fixed sized messages, size transmitted followed by message, delimiter bytes like newlines between messages, etc.